# What would happen to an adventurer's personal identity when turning into a God?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

I recently played RP with some friends, and one these friends is also one who's playing in the D&D campaign I DM (*Lost Mine Of Phandelver*).

While they were explaining me their home-made RP system, we came to talk about Gods.
After a bit of talking, my friend who is also playing D&D told me that he might someday try to achieve becoming a God.
It could be a logical way for his character, an elven wizard, as his goal is to be the most powerful magic caster that ever existed (The entire background may be a bit long to write here not not that relevant for this question).

I was thinking that he might someday become the new God of magic in place of [Mystra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystra_(Forgotten_Realms)).
I already know that a legendary adventurer becoming a God already happened, but it brings me to a few questions about what would happen :

1. Would the elven wizard keep his whole personality or would it be deeply affected by the previous God of magic memory and personality?
2. Will the new God be a God (male) or a Goddess as the previous one?

Comment: I guess that "whatever Ao says" is not an answer for you? Because by the very generic lore he could uplift someone, demote, merge deities, change them portfolios etc, so pretty much "anything goes". Also, Ao rules changed over time, so could you include in-game year this is happening?

Comment: @Mołot Yup I'd like something more precise, maybe backed up by precedent examples. It may not happen the year we're currently in in-game as it would take some time, but you can use the base of the LMOP in-game year, [1481 DR per this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/147103/51851).

Comment: While it would be very lengthy, the Riftwar universe series of books by Raymond Feist has this scenario, one of the chars becomes the god of magic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### They start with their own personality, yet they can and do change afterwards.

This question is rather difficult to answer in a manner that would satisfy everyone: it is best left to individual interpretations based on precedents. I suggest you have a look at the [list of deities who were previously mortals](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119012/which-deities-in-the-forgotten-realms-were-once-mortal/131532) and pick some examples and read about them on the [FR wiki](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Main_Page).

If you want to focus on a couple of well-documented examples, I would suggest you read on [Mystra](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Mystra), who has had at least three incarnations. The mortals who were chosen to carry the mantle by each previous incarnation carried some of their own personality with them, as evidenced by the [change in alignment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84925/has-a-god-ever-changed-alignment/105291#105291).

However it is also true that the personality can and does change to adapt to the job. [Kelemvor](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Kelemvor), the mortal lover of Midnight who became Mystra, was an unusual god of the dead right after his ascension. For example, he was "lenient" on the faithless and the false. Yet this created imbalance in the world and as time went on he readjusted himself for his job. Quoting from the FR wiki article:

> Kelemvor wondered how he could judge the damned, when he himself failed his own personal judgment. He gradually came to realize that there was nothing human in being a god. To correct his mistakes, great changes were undergone in his realm, as well as in himself. ... [Kelemvor] rid himself of all signs of humanity in order to properly fulfill his duties, ...

Kelemvor and Midnight's ascension and the ensuing changes in personality are described in the *Avatar Series* of novels, in particular the last novel of the series *Crucible: The Trial of Cyric the Mad*. Another ascended deity whose story is described in detail is [Finder Wyvernspur](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Finder_Wyvernspur) - his mortal life is recounted in the *Finder's Stone* trilogy, while he is a deity in the novels *Finder's Bane* and *Tymora's Luck*.

Comment: Selfishly, I wish this answer included a reading list. I'd be glad to branch out in what areas of FR-lore I've read, but FRwiki is sooooo frustratingly ad-slow and the references are so dense that I find it hard to find my own entry-point.

Comment: @nitsua60 I have added a paragraph describing the actual primary sources for Midnight and Kelemvor. I also mention Finder, whose ascension is also known in a lot of detail thanks to novels.

Comment: cool--thanks a bunch!

Comment: The FR wiki article also doesn't cite any source for the quoted paragraph (it's unclear whether it's from the same *Crucible* novel cited in the first paragraph of that section)...

Comment: @V2Blast I do not think the paragraph I quoted is itself a quote from *Crucible*, it is more like a summary of parts of the novel and it is a summary I agree with (though I must admit it has been a long time since I read it myself).

Comment: @ZwiQ: I wasn't saying the paragraph was a direct quote from Crucible, but rather that the *information* in your quote from the wiki article is not clearly sourced. Is it indeed from the *Crucible* novel? There's a citation in the first paragraph of the same section of the wiki article pointing to *Crucible*, but there are no other footnotes in that section.