# Do Forgotten Realms paladins have to follow a deity?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms, paladin, religions-and-deities

As can be seen in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51805/are-paladins-required-to-follow-a-god), with the relevant quote from the Players Handbook:

Player's Handbook, page 82:

> Although many paladins are devoted to gods of good, a paladin’s power comes as much from a commitment to justice itself as it does from a god.

However, while not an official ruling, [this series of tweets](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2019/04/24/does-a-paladin-need-to-serve-a-god-deity/) from Ed Greenwood counter this and states that in FR, they *are* required to follow a deity:

> One becomes a paladin by hearing and accepting a call to holy service. That acceptance is cemented by an oath. If a paladin transgresses against their oath, the usual absolution, as the PHB states, is to seek absolution from a cleric of the same faith. Paladins DO worship deities, and like any other mortal, may receive requests from mortal priests or divine servitors, or messages directly from a deity [...]
>
> [...] Although you, as a paladin, serve a god or alliance of good gods (to literally fight evil, and do so largely ‘in your own way'[) ...]
>
> [...] However, if your deity commands you to do something (like obey or work with a mortal priest) and you don’t, you shouldn’t expect to retain your paladinhood. What makes you a paladin is a “sacred oath,” and therefore the support of the gods [...]

Is this a valid ruling (i.e. it overrides the PHB as regards the Forgotten Realms) backed up with material from a sourcebook (And if so, which one), or is this just an unofficial stance/interpretation of a staff member?

The tweet suggests that Forgotten Realms paladins **do** have to follow a deity, which would be counter to the rules in the PHB. I'm looking for official, 5e, published material related to FR that supports that assertion.

Comment: @Medix2 - That is 5e/AL, this is regarding Forgotten Realms specifically. There is an unofficial quote from a game author saying FR paladins ***do*** need to follow a deity. I'm trying to find out if this is in a 5e book as an extra/setting type rule, or what.

Comment: @Raj It seems the question is asking whether Greenwood's claims are backed by official published D&D 5E material.  And by extension, whether it could be enforced as rules-as-written.

Comment: @Raj - Yes, that ^^ in absence of FR specific books to date.

Comment: @Raj True, the tweet is not rules-as written. However, the question is whether the tweet *refers to* some rules-as-written outside the PHB.

Comment: @Raj - I know that tweets are not official. And I know that 5e paladins do not have to follow a deity. The tweet suggests that *Forgotten Realms* paladins DO have to follow a deity, which would be counter to the PHB. I'm looking for official material related to FR that supports that assertion.

Comment: I'm going to suggest that people take any further debates about potential duplication to [Meta] (or just vote to close as a duplicate if you have the rep and feel strongly about it). If you have *questions* that might help focus the question or to determine if it is one or not, feel free to ask, but don't use this space for debating please.

Comment: Are you specifically including/excluding Oathbreakers? https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/paladin#Oathbreaker

Comment: @StuperUser - Either. Since that is source material, it's in the D&D multiverse, not FR. I don't *think* it would apply, but if you have a good answer for FR that uses that as a basis, I wouldn't kick it aside.

Answer (score 11):

#### Preamble

Let me start by stating two points that are relevant to this answer. Feel free to skip this section if you want to jump directly to the 5e material.

1. **In previous editions, official FR material dictated that paladins receive their powers from deities**. In general, deities are a major part of this polytheistic setting, and mortals and powers are well-aware of this. Deities get to run the (meta)physics of the world and not having faith diminishes their power and causes imbalance. Our real-world secular/religious sensitivities are not attuned to this way of thinking, perhaps a good analogy is having your children vaccinated. When most people have vaccination, we get a herd immunity; likewise **when most people have faith, the FR world 'runs'**. As such not just paladins, but all people are expected to have a patron deity. If not, they are "disciplined" in the afterlife and [become part of the "Wall of the Faithless"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62456/why-are-the-faithless-condemned-to-the-wall-of-the-faithless-after-death/62523#62523). The attempts by the god of the dead, Kelemvor, to resolve this seemingly unfair treatment of the faithless has been depicted to have serious consequences in novels, which resulted in a [change of his personality](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153256/what-would-happen-to-an-adventurers-personal-identity-when-turning-into-a-god/153263#153263).
2. In spite of the central role faith plays in the FR of Greenwood, you are more than welcome to reject it; or find ways around it (like a faithless paladin who is still being watched over by a deity like Torm). Throughout its whole history, Ed Greenwood and the various versions of any written material **have always highlighted the fact that each FR campaign belongs to the individual DMs**. So feel free to rule however you like.

As for the officially printed material you have asked for, below is what is available.

---

#### What do the 5e Sources Say?

*Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* states (page 131):

> When ... a warrior also has great devotion to a particular deity, that **god can reward the faithful with a measure of divine power, making that person
>   a paladin**.

And yet on page 132:

> Most paladins in the Forgotten Realms, like clerics, are devoted to a particular deity.

These two sentences might seem to be in conflict, unless we interpret them to state that 5e FR paladins get support from one or more deities. This interpretation is supported by lore from earlier editions (see for example the [Triadic Knights](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Triadic_knight)) as well as the text on clerics (page 125):

> A typical cleric in Faerun serves a single divine patron, but some individuals feel called to serve a group, ...

---

#### D&D Adventurer's League

It is worth noting that the *D&D Adventurer's League FAQ* has switched its position on this issue over time. (The change might be correlated with the introduction of non-FR campaigns to DDAL.) In [version 2.5](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/DDAL_FAQv25.pdf) it stated:

> Does My Paladin Have to Worship a Deity? Yes, though your character’s alignment isn’t required to match that of their deity.

While [version 3](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/DDADVL_FAQv3.pdf) states:

> No. What makes you think you do? Dunno what you’re talking about.

---

#### WotC Suggestions for Content Creators

Finally, Wizards of the Coast has a set of style guides for their official play writers and have been [made available](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/267467/DMs-Guild-Creator-Resource--Style-Guide-Resources) for all content creators on DM's Guild. Note that these guides are suggestions and not rules, but for the sake of completeness, I would like to quote the relevant parts. *D&D IP Guide* states:

> Divine magic is practiced by the most devoted followers of D&D’s gods: clerics and paladins. ... Paladins are the holy warriors of D&D. Like clerics, they serve a deity and channel divine power to achieve their goals (or the goals of the temple or holy order they serve).

*Forgotten Realms Style Guide* confirms:

> Paladins are warriors of unusual virtue and piety rewarded by a good god with divine power. ... paladins are typically judged more swiftly and harshly by their gods.

Comment: That tiny litte distinction between "are expected to have" and "are required to have" looks to be the crux of John's question.

Comment: Also doesn't "most paladins" from your second quote implicitly mean that paladins can exist without being devoted to a deity?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Gods in the Realms are well-known and are very real. There are people who remember their walking amongst the mortals. So it is well established lore of FR that deities are there, there is no logic in not believing in them; it is a clear two-way practical relationship between mortals and deities. And SCAG's treatment of the Fugue plane and the Wall of the Faithless agree completely with this lore.

Comment: @Rubikmoose that's actually slightly complex in FR as some deities have formed functional alliances and are sometimes worshipped as a collective (e.g. [The Triad](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/The_Triad)) including by clerics and paladins - such characters would not be devoted to "a particular deity" singular, but they would still be dependent on divine entities for their powers... (it's also sometimes been the case that gods have provided divine power even to those who do not venerate them, for whatever reasons that might still serve their ends.)

Comment: @ZwiQ I am aware of that.  The point isn't "does a paladin believe that gods exist" but "must a Paladin serve a deity."  I've not voted either way on your answer, since the FR assumptions are things that sort of carry over from one edition to another.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose The two sentences indeed seem to disagree with each other. Yet it is what is written, so I put it the way it is. The only reasonable interpretation is that even a paladin who is not explicitly following a given deity is still being supported by a number of deities. This is in accordance with past lore, for example there used to be paladins following the Triad (Torm, Tyr, Ilmater) in the past editions.

Comment: @ZwiQ FWIW, given the imprecision of the text available in SCAG, at the very least an Oath of Vengeance Paladin, and an Oath of the Crown paladin, could easily not serve a deity ... and yet, as you point out, the deity/deities might 'support' the paladin anyway!  *scratches head*

Comment: SCAG spends a paragraph to list deities also for Oath of Crown or Oath of Vengeance paladins.

Comment: @ZwiQ I'll take a look when I get home, not at books just now.

Comment: I think this answer would probably be improved by noting that the official FR material published in previous editions *does* mandate that paladins, and clerics, (and indeed druids - all divine casters, IIRC) must receive their powers from a deity (which is almost always, except for some unusual circumstances, their patron deity). 5e's official published FR material so far seems to strongly encourage that status quo but stops shy of stating it outright (seemingly except for the since-revised rule in DDAL that required such characters to worship a patron).

Comment: @Carcer Xanather's has a small section talking about being a cleric to an ideal (Or a paladin to an ideal, I can't quite remember) so seems to directly state "It doesn't have to be a God"
Also there's a recent interview where one of the highlights is I think Mearls mentioning this idea.

Whether it completely applies to just FR or in general, I don't think it applies in any specific or general way.

Comment: Your entire explanation is logically disconnected. Your first quote dictates one way for a paladin to be created, and then your second quote states that only "most" paladins use a diety, and you jump to say that the ones who don't devote themselves to a diety must have been created by the efforts of multiple deities? I don't see how that follows; why couldn't a non-deity force cause paladins (since the SCAG quote is `A if B` not `A iff B`)

Comment: @Carcer I tried to implement your suggestion. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Jihelu The part you remember is a sidebar in Xanathar's, on page 18. It specifically discusses different settings having different rules, so it is not FR material.

Comment: @ZwiQ Huh, thought it was a guideline. Didn't have the book to check.